# Falon 3.0 submodule not import while running windows executable(pyinstaller)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, falcon

I am using the falcon 3.1.0 framework for microservice development in my product. Also I am creating windows executable using pyinstaller 4.10. I can run microservice using gevent and also create windows executable using pyinstaller. While running the executable it failed to import the falcon submodules but for falcon 2.0 it works. It raises the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run_accountregistration.py", line 9, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
File "app.py", line 6, in <module>
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
File "falcon__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
File "falcon\app.py", line 22, in init falcon.app
ImportError: cannot import name app_helpers
[5848] Failed to execute script 'run_accountregistration' due to unhandled exception!
```

for falcon 2.0 it works

````
(accregisterenv) C:\MUM_DEV_TEAM\edcservices\accountregistration-ps>dist\run_accountregistration\run_accountregistration.exe
Directory  logs  Created
Directory  account_registration  Created
Successfully fetch connection details
Server start running at 127.0.0.1:8005```
````

Comment: This is most likely caused by what `pyinstaller` calls a "hidden import", that is, one that its static analysis cannot detect. Because `pyinstaller` doesn't know about the module, it does not include it in the `.exe`. The documentation has a very helpful section called *When things go wrong*.  I suggest you work through it.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Added following  hidden import in pyinstaller spec files.
hiddenimports=['falcon.app_helpers', 'xml.etree', 'responders'] .
Now executable import falcon app_helpers submodule but its not import responders submodule from falcon.